# Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/do'

Tags: angular6

I have created an Angular component in which I am importing rxjs do operator.

But getting error cant resolve.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/Members/member-messages/member-messages.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/do' in 'C:\Demo\DatingApDemo\DatingApp\src\app\Members\member-messages'
```

What is the solution for this?

Thank you,
Sharayu

Comment: Angular 6 depends on RxJS6, which uses pipeable operators. Not these old, deprecated operators. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md, https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

Comment: thank you @JBNizet.
I had tried that also. (do -> tap).
but then it says .tap() is not a function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally, I am able to solve that issue.

do() is replaced by tap().

for reference https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

and 
tap() should be inside .pipe().

like this, .pipe(tap())

for more reference, you can refer this link,

https://alligator.io/angular/angular-6/

and

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html